# Об объёме волос

Tags: фразеология

Объём, как известно, измеряем, но ведь он подразумевает телесность или же вместимость, что указывает на плотность. Налицо противоречие. Не правильнее будет говорить о *пышности*? Смысл этого слова включает и объёмность тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу никакого противоречия, пышные волосы ― это волосы, занимающие большой прикорневой объем.

**Между объемом, массой и плотностью существует простая зависимость**: m= ρV Здесь: V — прикорневой объем волос, m — масса волос, ρ — плотность волос в прикорневом  объеме, тогда **V = m/ρ.**

Конечно, все хотят увеличить объем волос, чтобы прическа казалась пышной. Но чтобы увеличить объем, надо **увеличить массу волос и уменьшить их плотность** в прикорневом объёме, то есть распределить волосы по большому пространству.

**Увеличить массу волос сложно** (для этого требуется густой и толстый от природы волос), а вот плотность массы волос может меняться. Например, жирные волосы быстро слипаются уже на второй-третий день после мытья, тогда  плотность их массы увеличивается, а объем соответственно уменьшается, волосы делаются менее пышными.

Итак, получить хороший объем волос можно  **путем уменьшения их плотности**, тогда одна и та же масса волос будет занимать большее пространство. Для этого используют начёсы, завивки, особые стрижки, а также различные химические средства.

**Дополнение**

Мне кажется, что я не очень ясно обозначила следующее. Объём пышных волос **увеличивается** за счёт **воздушной прослойки** между волосами, они располагаются не совсем близко друг к другу, и тогда плотность этого  объёма (волосы + воздух) **уменьшается**. При этом масса прикорневого  объема практически не изменяется: это масса самих волос + очень маленькая масса добавленного воздуха, которую можно не учитывать.

Comment: Всегда думал, что объём трёхмерен, ан нет, — есть другая правда.

Comment: Сибилла даёт абсолютно правильную формулу объёма:
V — объем тела (м³),
m — масса тела, (килограмм),
ρ — плотность вещества, (кг/м³).  Так что, трёхмерный он, как ни крути.

Comment: «Объём пышных волос увеличивается за счёт воздушной прослойки.» Так говорит Sibylla. За счёт воздуха. Но, почему же тогда — объём волос увеличивается? Определённо: или объёмность, или пышность. Причёска — не тело, а пространственная конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Решила соединить свои комментарии в ответ и дополнить их.

"*Определённо: или объёмность, или пышность. Причёска — не тело, а пространственная конструкция".*

Пространственная конструкция тоже имеет такую характеристику, как ***занимаемый*** объём.

1. Вы принесли перевязанную ёлку домой.  Дёрнули за верёвочку - ветви дерева начали расходиться в стороны, т.е. начали занимать в пространстве б**о**льшее место, б**о**льший объём. А ведь масса ёлки осталась прежней, изменилась только ее ***пространственная*** плотность. Деревце стало ПЫШНЫМ, ОБЪЁМНЫМ.
   А женщина с химической завивкой или а-ля Анжела Дэвис? И объём "не мелкий", и пышность "не придавлена".
2. **Иногда объемный не есть пышный.**
   Вспомните панковский ирокез: на почти лысой голове разноцветный гребень. Эта прическа **объёмна**, но **не пышна**.
   А знаменитая "тимошенковская" коса вокруг головы? Волосы гладкие, и объём имеет только собственно коса, иногда многослойная. Такой *венок*  "приличен" по объёму, но пышным Вы его не назовете.
3. **И совсем наоборот**.
   Мужчина с женщиной пошли купаться: у него короткие волосы, а у неё - до пояса... Через десять минут после водных процедур мужской ёжик высыхает и становится  **пышным** на полтора сантиметра вокруг головы. А женская грива, если вы её соберёте на макушке, и мокрая по **объёму** будет гораздо больше.

   Так что в итоге "образовалась"  физико-парикмахерская Антанта - с ракурсом на красоту.

Comment: Спасибо и хорошо, что не формулами аргументируете. «Пространственная конструкция тоже имеет...» Нет, не имеет. Только видимость габаритов, т.к. нет у неё оболочки. И видимость эту можно обозначить понятийными словами (объёмность и причёска), при этом никак не обращаясь к абсолютным величинам. И правильно в Ответе: прическа объёмна, а не объём причёски. И коса, конечно, не пышная и не объёмная, Она — толстая и (или) длинная.

Comment: @shampar И не собиралась я ничего аргументировать формулами ( а они есть! И для пространственных конструкций - тоже ). И к абсолютным величинам я абсолютно не обращалась. Это ВЫ сомневались в трехмерности объема ( а значит, и пышности ),  поэтому я и указала в комментарии,  поддерживая Сибиллу,  где -килограммы, а где - кубометры...

Comment: Всегда думал, что объём трёхмерен, ан нет, — есть другая правда. – shampar 3 мар в 19:44.

Comment: "Всегда думал, что объём трёхмерен, ан нет, — есть другая правда"...   Да хоть по десятому разу! - зачем же передергивать-то?  Вы упустили  " ρ " — плотность вещества, (кг/м³): те же килограммы и те же кубометры,  только деленные друг на друга (специально не "грузила" лишнего ).  Насколько велика Ваша нелюбовь к формулам, настолько же они - формулы - правильны.

Comment: «Другая правда» упускает, что вещество здесь неоднородно, оно — сумма двух. У Sibylla в её замечательной формуле 4D заложено. О какой трёхмерности речь? Фокусы с формулами смешны.

Comment: 4D,  так 4D.  Ну, например,  "4D-плетеная, пироуглерод" ( тип матрицы ) имеет дополнительные характеристики материалов: прочность при растяжении σ1+, МПа; прочность при сжатии σ1−, МПа; модуль упругости Е1, ГПа; теплопро-водность λ , Вт/(м·К); КЛТР α ·10-6,1/К...  Уравнение баланса масс составляющих (...),  где  ...объемы волокон, кокса, пор и общий фиксированный объем УУКМ; ξ - коэффициент объемной усадки ... в фиксированном объеме, равный произведению линейных коэффициентов усадки
по осям X ,Y и Z... и проч.проч.  И ничего смешного нет, правда?

Comment: Лучше про мокрых мужчину и женщину.

Comment: Согласна и рада, что хоть какой-то  "консенсус образовался", что мне хоть в чем-то удалось Вас переубедить. А то мы так долго пикировались...